# Use salt to determine IP of the host machine for Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, salt-stack

I need to automate the detection of the host machine IP during a `vagrant up` in order to build a config file. Is there an easy way to do this using Saltstack?

Comment: `network.ip_addrs`? It's not really clear how you're intending to combine vagrant and salt. If you mean the IP address for the salt master, usually people use DNS.